# Get time Difference in Minutes

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two buttons in my Application "Start" and "Stop".

When a user clicks on the Start button, LabelStartTime.Text contains current System time(HH:MM AM/PM).

When a user clicks on the Stop Button LabelStopTime.Text contains current System time and LabelTotle.Text

I am trying to show the Time difference in Minutes. I only know how to get current time to the Label value.

`lblCurrentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();`  // Get current time

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCurrentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); // get system time to the  Start time 

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Stop();

        textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        lblCurrentPrice.Text = Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes; 



    }
```

this -- > `Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes` Given Error

Comment: Parse the two time values to `TimpeSpan`, then get their difference using subtraction `ts2 - ts1`, later you get TotalMinutes like `(ts2 - ts1).TotalMinutes`

Comment: `DateTime - DateTime` will give you a Timespan without parsing them first

Comment: @Jonesy, In that case the OP has to keep the start `DateTime` and end DateTime somewhere in the code, Since have is showing only time part then parsing it to time span would be feasible.

Comment: Please read [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Comment: It should be `stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes.ToString();`,

Comment: I did but give same Error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class. Call `Start()` when the first button is clicked, and `Stop()` when the second button is clicked. Then, the difference in minutes is `Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes;`

In the code example you've now given you've declared two `new` stopwatches that only exist within the scope of each method.

Declare it outside the methods like this:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get system time to the  Start time 
    lblCurrentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); 

    stopWatch.Start();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopWatch.Stop();

    textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    lblCurrentPrice.Text = Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes; 
}
```

Comment: Wow @webturner didn't even know you could do that with `Elapsed` - nice.

Comment: Sir, Can u explain feather how to do it im interresting

Comment: @DinoBaba Read the documentation and look at the examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: @webturner Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes line given Error i edit my post help me

Comment: Just so you know... You shouldn't edit your original question to ask something else as it invalidates any answers that have been given already. Also you should say what the error is.

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Elapsed.get' This is the Error that i getting

Comment: @DinoBaba Did you even read the documentation I linked? If you did, you'd see an example on how to actually create a Stopwatch object properly. You cannot call it like that, it is not static.